# Firebase Functions (trigger) “dynamically” write/update Firebase node

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I am wanting to retrieve data from a Firebase Node Games/{gid}/BoxScores which has four child nodes: `Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4`

Below is the code I'm trying to implement; where qtrDesc is the reference to any one of those child nodes in BoxScores: `Q1 or Q2 or Q3 or Q4`

```
exports.boxScoresUpdate = functions.database.ref('/Games/{gid}/BoxScores').onWrite(event => { 

    event.data.ref.parent.child('Qtr').once('value', data => {

        console.log('Qtr is: ', data.val());

        for(let i = data.val(); i > 0; i--) {

            let qtrDesc = "Q".concat(i);

            console.log('qtrDesc: ', qtrDesc); // Outputs the desired 'Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4'

            // Outputs is "undefined" in the function logs
            console.log('Qtr Score is: ', newValue.qtrDesc); // ****Does not reference the desired child node

        }

    });

});
```

The problem with the code above is that the output in the logs on the Firebase functions dashboard is `undefined` as it is attempting to get the `newValue` for `qtrDesc` (which does not exist) instead of the `newValue` for `Q1 or Q2 or Q3 or Q4` as desired!?

The json node is:

```
"Games": {
    "12345": {
        "Date": "20170819",
        "BoxScores": {
            "Q1": "10",
            "Q2": "21",
            "Q3": "90",
            "Q4": "100"
        },
        "Qtr": "4"
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be certain without seeing your data structure. But I think you're looking for:

```
event.data.ref.parent.child('Qtr').once('value', data => {
    data.forEach(quarterSnap => {
        let qtrDesc = quarterSnap.key;
        let qtrVal = quarterSnap.val();

        console.log(qtrDesc, qtrVal);
    }
});
```

If that's not what you need, please edit your question to include a snippet of the JSON structure you're using (as text, no screenshots). You can get this by clicking the "Export JSON" link in your [Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data).

Comment: It didnt work, the forEach loop never gets called. I updated the question to include the json object.

Comment: That means that you're listening to a node that doesn't have any data. That makes sense, since I don't really see in the JSON how `Qtr` to `event.data.ref.parent.child('Qtr').once('value', data => {` would result in a loop. Aren't you trying to loop over `event.data.val()`?

Comment: `event.data.val()` would (or should) result in the value `4`, as seen in the json object above. Then the `for` loop "should" loop four times, changing the `qtrDesc` variable to the following values: `Q4 then Q3 then Q2 and finally Q1` as I'm expecting with the `"Q".concat(i)` line and then I am expecting to read the `newValue.qtrDesc` from the `BoxScores` node to retrieve the values as such: `100, 90, 21, and then 10`

Comment: My issue is (or seems like) that `newValue.qtrDesc` is looking for a node called `qtrDesc` in the `BoxScores` node instead of it dynamically changing in the for loop (as I expected): `newValue.Q4`, `newValue.Q3`, `newValue.Q2` and finally `newValue.Q1`

Comment: Aha... that means you're looking for `newValue[qtrDesc]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);
```

and

```
admin.database();
```

for references